# Tkinker Text and Speech Recognition

Tags: python, tkinter, while-loop, speech-recognition, python-multithreading

I am having a problem with tkinter and speech recognition. I am creating a chatbot however I couldn't make speech recognition and tkinter text work together at the same time when I click on the mic button. I tried threading but couldn't make it work smoothly...

I also tried to put speech recognition in a while loop so that users don't need to click on the mic button everytime they tried to speak because I wanted users to be able to talk to the bot until he/she gets to the next chapter... I couldn't make it either...

The problem is when I use `threading` and `while` loops speech recognition starts working even if I don't click on the mic button and also it keeps working when I skip the chapter... Can anyone please help me figure it out?

[image: screenshot]

```
def record_audio():
    global r
    global talk

    def txtEvent(event):
        if event.state == 12 and event.keysym == 'c':
            return
        else:
            return "break"

    txt.bind("<Key>", lambda e: txtEvent(e))

    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=1)
            voice = r.listen(source)
            text_punk = r.recognize_google(voice, language="en-US")
            text_punk = text_punk.lower()
            punk_screen = "You---> " + text_punk
            txt.insert(END, "\n" + punk_screen)


            if text_punk != '':
                test=testpy.Testing()
                res = test.response(text_punk)
                txt.insert(END, "\n" + 'Bot---> ' + res)
                talk(res)

    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        txt.insert(END, "\n" + "System could not recognize your voice")

    except sr.RequestError:
        txt.insert(END, "\n" + 'Sorry, the speech service is down')


mic_btt = Button(frame_button, image=mic_icon_rsd, bd=0, bg="#2d4d82",
                 activebackground="#2d4d82",command= record_audio)
mic_btt.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.1)
```

Comment: You will have to use a thread, but you can set a global flag that the thread reads that tells it whether recognition should be "on" or "off", right?

Comment: `tkinter` doesn't support multithreading in the sense that only one thread can access if there's more than one. In addition, any non-threaded code that is run cannot take too much time because otherwise it will interfere with its `mainloop()` and make the GUI "freeze". There are many questions here on both of those topics — in some cases there are workarounds.

Comment: You can run the text to speech code in a thread. As long as you don't directly access tkinter widgets in this other thread it should work just fine.